# IMAP: (JavaMail) UIDVALIDTY values always changes of some folders

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap

We have implemented a mail client using JavaMail api which connects to the mail server for handling messages in IMAP protocol. The implemenetation works fine on many customers and mailservers, but one customer we have a problem,

**UIDVALIDTY:** to determine whether we can rely on UID values of messages in a folder, we store the recent UIDVALIDTY of each folder. And on the next process, we compare the recent stored value with the current. If they are same, we can rely on the UIDs. The IMAP specification requires that servers do their best to avoid unnecessary changes to this value. (Except mail server crash, restart, upgrade etc)

On this specific customers mail server, the UIDVALIDTY values of some folders change every time. The test account has 300 folders, 15 of them always the same specific defined folders, have always different UIDVALIDTY values.

What can be reason for that? Is there a mail server setting? I think it is beyond the scope of java mail api, it is mail server related. The customer says we have no problem with our mail server and we can use it with our web interface. How can I persuade and convine the customer that there is a problem on their mail server?

Answer (score 3):

Some mailbox formats have no space to store UIDs, and I think a couple of still-used servers support such formats. Dovecot notably supports many storage formats, IIRC including one that doesn't support UIDs.

If a server has to, it'll [send you a UIDNOTSTICKY response code when you open the mailbox](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4315#page-4) and from that point it'll conjure new UIDS out of thin air. You may detect UIDNOTSTICKY and refuse to play, or just see it as an opportunity to test your validity change handling.

Comment: can we detect UIDNOTSTICKY using java mail api?

Comment: Seems so. I'm not sure, but it seems likely that you get a StoreEvent that [you can listen for](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Store.html#addStoreListener(javax.mail.event.StoreListener)). If that's suppressed due to lack of human-readable text, you can always subclass IMAPStore, reimplement `handleResponseCode()`, check for UIDNOTSTICKY and call `super.handleResponseCode()`. But listening for a StoreEvent is nicer.

Comment: You can enable [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) to see if you're getting that response code, but even if you are it's not clear you could do anything different.  You either have to assume the mailbox is different every time you see it, or you have to invent your own heuristics to try to determine whether any cached information is still valid.  I assume these mailboxes aren't actually being deleted and recreated every time you see them, right?  What sort of mail server is the customer using?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, the boxes are not actually being deleted or recreated. We have more than 300 folders, only same 15 of them change often their UIDVALIDTY, but the messages remain same. They are using Groupwise.